# Magento API REST customer not redirecting to Authentication Page

Tags: api, magento, authentication, redirect

I am trying to access products through Customer account. To achieve this I am using sample code from [oauth_customer.php](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html) magento documentation page. 
`Everything is okay and working fine; but the thing I am facing is that whenever I login as customer after successful login page redirects to the Customer Dashboard instead of redirecting to the Authentication URL.` To do so I have to past the URL link again manually, so it redirects to the Authentication page and after authentication it shows whatever I want.
I have also tried to extend the account controller from a sample code from link: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzCDl5a0zmSVdWdFMG9jMTB1TXM/edit?pli=1 
But still there is no luck. Is there anyway to make a callback URL again after login like we do in admin authentication side?

Answer (score 1):

At last I found the solution myself. I decided to post here so it might be helpful for someone. Well by following the sample code from : `https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzCDl5a0zmSVdWdFMG9jMTB1TXM/edit?pli=1` I was able to get the redirect url. But the redirected path moved to 404 page as the redirect adds the redirect link with site URL. The code for redirecting to URL was `$this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));`
I changed this code to  `header( "refresh:1;url=".$session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));` So it redirected to the Authorization page successfully. I assume that magento takes some miliseconds to create its cookies. So I added some refresh time to it. Here is the AccountController class code:
{yourmagento}/app / code / community / Chalkfy / OAuthRedirect / controllers / AccountController.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Chalkfly_OAuthRedirect_AccountController  extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {
    protected  function  _loginPostRedirect()
    {
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        // if this redirect is a result of the OAuth process, force the redirect
        if(stristr($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),"oauth/authorize?oauth_token=") == 0 )
        {
            echo "Redirecting Please Wait..";
            // Redirect to the URL after get
            header( "refresh:1;url=".$session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));

            // $this->_redirect($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));

        }
        else {
            parent::_loginPostRedirect();
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Oauth, the oauth consumer login form redirects to customer/account/loginPost.

The loginPost function redirects you to customer/account/login because the parameter formkey is missing.

Just add this in app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml at the end of the form tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Redirect will work fine when you add this. Tested in Magento CE 1.9.0.0, EE 1.14.1.x

Comment: Well that seems to stop the oauth login page redirecting to the regular login page - but now it just redirects to the dashboard. How do you make it redirect back to the app? If you happen to be logged in to the store in another tab, for example, then the oauth "consumer" app leads to the oauth authorisation page rather than the oauth login page, and the authorisation page redirects back to the app just fine. The login should be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the controller or create an observer.

Here is a link that fix you issue: http://blog.belvg.com/magento-tips-how-to-redirect-a-user-to-other-page-than-his-account-page-after-login-in-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

As [bas_van_poppel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706360/bas-van-poppel) said, by adding the form key to the appropiate phtml, you get rid of the redirect to the regular login page.

In order to avoid the redirection to the dashboard page and get redirected to your app, you need to remove the call to `setAfterAuthUrl` in the `_initForm` method on `app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/AuthorizeController.php`:

```
    /** @var $helper Mage_Core_Helper_Url */
    $helper = Mage::helper('core/url');
    $session // We don't want this: ->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login', array('_nosid' => true)))
            ->setBeforeAuthUrl($helper->getCurrentUrl());
```

After a successful login, Magento redirects the customer to the after_auth_url value in the customer session, if the value is not specified, it will redirect you to the value of before_auth_url.

This is just for illustrative purposes, you should follow best practices to override this core controller.