# Using Magento Rest API with angularjs and OAuth

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, magento, oauth

**Edit:** TL;DR
Is there anyone who uses Magento Rest API with angularjs and could give me some hints on how to get started with OAuth?

I'm trying to use the magento Rest API with angularjs. My Problem is that I don't even get the initiate endpoint to work.

To calculate the signature I used https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js :

```
var initEndpointUrl = "http://magentoserver.com/oauth/initiate"

var parameters = {
    oauth_callback: callback,
    oauth_consumer_key : consumerKey,
    oauth_nonce : nonce,
    oauth_signature_method : signatureMethod,
    oauth_timestamp : timestamp            
}

var signature = oauthSignature.generate('POST', initEndpointUrl, parameters, consumerSecret);
```

I've tried two different approaches:

1: Send the parameters with the Authorization Header:

```
var authHeader = "OAuth "+ 
    "oauth_callback=" + callback + "," +
    "oauth_consumer_key=" + consumerKey + "," +
    "oauth_nonce=" + nonce + "," +
    "oauth_signature_method=" + signatureMethod +  "," +
    "oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp + "," +
    "oauth_signature=" + signature;   

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: initEndpointUrl,
    header: {
        'Authorization': authHeader
    }
})
```

The Problem with this approach is, that I get a **400 Bad Request** for the *OPTIONS* method from the server. This is caused (as far as I read) by the request not being a "Simple Request" because of the Authentication header. This in the Pre-flight the *OPTIONS* method is called.

2: Send the parameters as url parameter:

```
http://magentoserver.com/oauth/initiate?
    oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&
    oauth_consumer_key=12345&
    oauth_nonce=67890&
    oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
    oauth_timestamp=1234567890&
    oauth_signature=abcdefg1234567
```

With this approach I had more success and was able to add all required parameters until the signature was checked, which resulted in **401 oauth_problem=signature_invalid**.

I'm quite new to OAuth so I'm thinking maybe the call for generating the signature wasn't correct. On the other hand I could imagine, that by changing the parameters (and with it the URL) I invalidate the signature.

Anybody has experience with this? Thanks in advance!

PS: I already posted this on https://magento.stackexchange.com/, because I thought it would be more magento specific.

Comment: I tested with [several](http://quonos.nl/oauthTester/) [signature](http://nouncer.com/oauth/signature.html) [testers](http://jrconlin.github.io/OAuthTestPage/#instructions) and tried all kinds of different things. Still Magento says the signature is invalid. Is it correct to sign _oauth_callback_ with the other parameters?

Comment: You definitely want to be using a header and not passing the required items as parameters.  The first thing that caught my eye is that your header is malformed.  Each variable must be wrapped in double quotes so you must either escape a set up quotes or do this 'oauth_signature="' + signature + '"';.  Notice the use of single and double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried that, but I still run into the OPTIONS problem I get when testing in the browser if I don't use the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of help from Nic Raboy we got it included in his OAuth Library:

[ng-cordova-oauth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth)

The library does all the signing, nonce calculation and everything else that is needed. It does however require to run on cordova (using the inAppBrowser plugin).

Before that worked there had to be some fixes for Magento:

[OAuth activation if initiate directs to 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472228/magento-rest-api-oauth-url-returning-404)

[OAuth fix for missing form_key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992987/magento-api-rest-customer-not-redirecting-to-authentication-page)

[OAuth fix for redirecting to dashboard](https://gist.github.com/SchumacherFM/9774636)

The last one didn't work on instant, but it is the right direction. If anyone has questions about this, please feel free to ask. I was really surprised that it took this much effort to get it to run.

Thanks Nic, it's really easy now to get the access_token :)

Comment: To summarize.  The oauth_callback has to be included in the request token header and the access token request must be signed by both the client secret and the token secret obtained from the request token.

Comment: As I also struggled with the decision if using header parameters or url parameters I want to point out that in this solution the oauth_callback parameter is transferred once in the header and once as url parameter. Didn't test if this is needed, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am just using OAuth in PHP. I hope to it help you.

Look this example link. When use 'oauth/initiate', oauth_callback is included on URL. Write it both sides

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html#OAuthAuthentication-PHPExamples

And I saw other OAuth header there are using double quotation marks every value as oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I just tried both (double quotes and putting the encoded URL to the url parameters). I'm aware of the example, but it doesn't really help so much, because I've to create the nonce, the timestamp and most importantly the signature myself. And this might very easily be where I make my mistake. Also I think it might have something to do with the pre-flight OPTIONS call...